# sql: map data provided in query

Tags: mysql

I want to provide a list inside a query eg. like this:

```
('val1', 'res1')
('val2', 'res2')
(...)
```

Now I run a query where I fetch val1, val2 etc.

```
select * from values;
val1
val2
...
```

These values should be replaced by the list I provided in the select statement, something like:

```
select * values /* add some magic here */;
val1 | res1
val2 | res2
...
```

The thing is: 'res1' etc. is not stored in the database. I can only provide the mapping within the query. Is this even possibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
select val,
       (case val
            when 'val1' then 'res1'
            when 'val2' then 'res2'
        end) as res
from values;
```

Comment: That was quick (my reply wasn't). Thanks!